# Error: error while writing **** File name too long

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2

I'm trying to assemble an Android build with my laptop with Ubuntu but I'm getting constantly the error on a file generated by dagger:

```
error: error while writing DaggerMyLibraryBookmarksComponent$com_testx_baseapplication_presentation_common_dagger_component_ApplicationComponent_userManagerRepository.class (File name too long)
```

This error is quite weird due that in other computers with same code and same SO I'm able to compile the project without any issue.

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: what is the name of the file? how long is the name?

Comment: DaggerMyLibraryBookmarksComponent$com_testx_baseapplication_presentation_common_dagger_component_ApplicationComponent_userManagerRepository.class

Comment: which version of dagger are you using? this should have been fixed in [2.11](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.11-rc2)

Answer (score 7):

The problem here was that I was using an encrypted folder in my /home partition. I just created a new folder outside the encrypted partition and the problem was solved.

This is due encrypted folders only accepts 144bytes class name files.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here!
My solution was to create a virtual image using "dd", format it in ext4 and mount it in my working folder. Worked like a charm!

Somthing like this:
https://www.tecmint.com/create-virtual-harddisk-volume-in-linux/